# Find line number of XML string based on XPath

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I'm trying to find the line in a multi-line string, containing XML, that a given Xpath points to.

In other words, I have a string containing XML. I have a given Xpath, that I want to use to find the exact line line number of the string.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Is you goal to visualize XPath selection OR some fishy patching of XML with string concatenation? Do you need to handle generic XML or you can enforce XML structure (i.e. one-node-per-line as in Ann L's +1 answer)? Side note: please avoid "what is the best way" in your questions without defining your "better" criteria.

Comment: This is not a bad question :( it's just missing the "what I have tried so far" bit. One real use-case I have right now is where I know the element under a certain xpath has a bug in it, and I'd like to print out the line number so I can move there quickly with my editor and fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using a an [XmlTextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hh47ty4.aspx) instead.  That has LineNumber and LinePosition properties.

The `XmlTextReader` does have some limited "read until you reach such-and-such a node" properties, but they aren't as sophisticated as those of XPath.  Depending on how complex the XPath is, this might or might not work.

I did find a link on the subject [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/get-line-numbers-evaluating-xpath-expressions-t3326046.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can load the XML from the string into an actual XML class.

```
XDocument x = XDocument.Parse(yourStringContainingXML);
string contentOfNode = x.Descendants(XName.Get("NameOfTheNode")).First().Value;
```

Comment: He's looking for the line number not the value.